# Finding the maximum value of an array of nullable numbers in TypeScript using spread operator

Tags: typescript

I have an array of nullable numbers like this:

```js
let myArray : Array<number | null> = [1,2,null,4,null,5];
let maximumOfMyArray = Math.max(...myArray); // Type null is not assignable to type number
```

I am happy to have JavaScript treat null as 0 in this case.
I can think of two possible solutions, neither of which are ideal:

```js
let myArray : Array<number | null> = [1,2,null,4,null,5];
//@ts-ignore
let maximumOfMyArray = Math.max(...myArray);
```

Which doesn't really address the problem, and:

```js
let myArray : Array<number | null> = [1,2,null,4,null,5];
let castArray = myArray as unknown as Array<number>;
let maximumOfMyArray = Math.max(...myArray);
```

Is there a solution that doesn't use these workarounds?

Comment: Side note: `...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what rest and spread do. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a solution that doesn't use these workarounds?

Yes: Explicitly convert the `null`s to `0` via `map`:

```typescript
let maximumOfMyArray = Math.max(...myArray.map(v => v === null ? 0 : v));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggJwQQxhAXBRKYB4B2ArlAEYgIQA+ERwwAfBALwQDaAjADQBMntwnACx9CdTgFYAugG4AUKEhRkADwCWUYgHkAZgFl4SVMwi7kYABYA6JcoAUlh7GypryAA62Abs0bem-mlFgCAB+CAAGDAhPAEoY6SA)

Unless you map the `null`s to numbers (or filter them out; see below), your only other choice **is** a workaround such as the ones you've shown, because you're asking TypeScript to ignore the fact that `null` isn't a number, and TypeScript's whole reason for being is to not munge types like that. :-)

---

I was sorry to see that just `filter`ing the `null`s out didn't make TypeScript happy without a type assertion (not even with `typeof v === "number"`), but it does at least let you do the type assertion without `unknown`:

```typescript
const myArrayWithoutNulls = myArray.filter(v => v !== null) as Array<number>;
let maximumOfMyArray = Math.max(...myArrayWithoutNulls);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggJwQQxhAXBRKYB4B2ArlAEYgIQA+ERwwAfBALwQDaAjADQBMntwnACx9CdTgFYAugG4AUAGMA9vgDOkWNlQB1AJZgAFosJgAcqOArm0eElQA6AGY7gYcgAoAbs0ZeAhExZ+AEoIZEtNPCJScno5UHVkAA8dKGIAeQcAWRscK0zkAzsoJLc7Mo1bGF0DI1NzFSDpIA)

Or **much** better that doing that, use a type guard function as [Denis Frezzato shows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5678644/denis-frezzato) in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67175577/157247).

Comment: myArray.filter(v => v !== null) returns Array<number | null> unfortunately, so an annoying cast to number[] is needed

Comment: @Eoin - Hit refresh, I'd updated the answer when I realized that. :-)

Comment: There is no need of that unsafe casting, you can use a type guard.

Comment: Accepted, I like the explicit conversion to 0's; it also makes it much clearer what the intended behaviour is. Thank you!

Comment: @DenisFrezzato - A type guard function like your `isDefined` is still effectively an assertion -- but it's a ***much*** better form of assertion IMHO, not least because it's backed up by reusable code ensuring it. :-) Thank you for pointing that out, and for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67175577/157247).

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the array with a type guard

```js
declare const ns: Array<number | null>
declare const isDefined: <A>(a: A | null | undefined) => a is A

Math.max(...ns.filter(isDefined)) // number
```

Comment: FWIW, a playground link doing the above: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggJwQQxhAXBRKYB4B2ArlAEYgIQA+ERwwAfBALwQDaAjADQBMntwnACx9CdTgFYAugG4AUADNC+AMZgAlgHt8ENQGcAIiHlr8IACa449ABTJMcKjVHBHSs0ZPmAlJmQ7dWBAA3rIQYRAI4IQI2n4AhEws-BAAZCkQ8YkQbh6mZnIAvnLKWrqQsNioAOpqYAAWGoRgAHLOASwVSKgAdMbAYOTWeobGeV5yoOXIAB5qUMQA8vIAsvBdaCzLyPXdUDPW3YedODX1jS1t40A

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to the one suggest by @T.J. Crowder is to extend the definition of `Math.max` to include `null` values, This way your original code will works without change.

in a `.d.ts` file add this:

```
declare global {
  interface Math {
    max(...values: (number | null)[]): number
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also a good solution. For my use case T.J. Crowder's answer is better; this one might confuse other devs as we extend a well known definition. Not to say that it wouldn't be a good solution for another team/ project though; thank you!

Comment: Since the actual `max` function does accept `null` values, I think this might be a valid extension of the interface, but I understand this might feel like "magic" and less explicit than the other answers